# Prevent reading the same record with Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I use Hibernate 5 and Oracle 12.
With the below query I want to randomly select an Entity from a set of Entity's:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entity e ... <CONDITIONS> ... AND ROWNUM = 1");
Optional<Entity> entity = query.list().stream().findAny();
// Change the entity in some way. The changes will also make sure that the entity won't appear in the next query run based on <CONDITIONS>
        ...
```

This works but only if all the transactions that execute the code run sequentially. Thus I also want to make sure that the entity that has already been read won't be read in another transaction.
I tried it with locking:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("SELECT e FROM Entity e ... <CONDITIONS> ... AND ROWNUM = 1")
.setLockMode("this", LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
```

But it seems that Hibernate converts this construct to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` which doesn't prevent the other transaction from reading the entity, waiting till the other transactions using it commits and then applying their own changes on the entity.

Is it possible to set some kind of lock on the entity so that it disappears guaranteed from the query result in another transaction?

I've written some experimental code to understand how locking works in Hibernate. It simulates two transactions whose key steps (select and commit) can be executed in different order by adjusting the parameters of `transaction()` method. This time `Field` is used instead of `Entity`, but it doesn't matter. Each transaction reads the same `Field`, updates its `description` attribute and commits.

```
    private static final LockMode lockMode = LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE;

    enum Order {T1_READS_EARLIER_COMMITS_LATER, T2_READS_EARLIER_COMMITS_LATER};

    @Test
    public void firstReadsTheOtherRejected() {

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        // It looks like the transaction that commits first is the only transaction that can make changes.
        // The changes of the other one will be ignored.
        final Order order = Order.T1_READS_EARLIER_COMMITS_LATER;
//        final Order order = Order.T2_READS_EARLIER_COMMITS_LATER;

        es.execute(() -> {
            switch (order) {
                case T1_READS_EARLIER_COMMITS_LATER:
                    transaction("T1", 1, 8);
                    break;
                case T2_READS_EARLIER_COMMITS_LATER:
                    transaction("T1", 4, 1);
                    break;
            }
        });

        es.execute(() -> {
            switch (order) {
                case T1_READS_EARLIER_COMMITS_LATER:
                    transaction("T2", 4, 1);
                    break;
                case T2_READS_EARLIER_COMMITS_LATER:
                    transaction("T2", 1, 8);
                    break;
            }
        });

        es.shutdown();

        try {
            es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void transaction(String name, int delayBeforeRead, int delayBeforeCommit) {
        Transaction tx = null;
        Session session = null;

        try {
            session = factory.openSession();

            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(delayBeforeRead);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Field f WHERE f.description=?1").setLockMode("this", lockMode);
            query.setString("1", DESC);
            Field field = (Field) query.uniqueResult();
            String description1 = field.getDescription();
            System.out.println(name + " : FIELD READ " + description1);

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(delayBeforeCommit);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            field.setDescription(name);
            session.update(field);
            System.out.println(name + " : FIELD UPDATED");

            tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail();
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        System.out.println(name + " : COMMITTED");
    }
```

and the output:

```
T1 : FIELD READ This is a field for testing
апр 19, 2019 5:28:01 PM org.hibernate.loader.Loader determineFollowOnLockMode
WARN: HHH000445: Alias-specific lock modes requested, which is not currently supported with follow-on locking; all acquired locks will be [PESSIMISTIC_WRITE]
апр 19, 2019 5:28:01 PM org.hibernate.loader.Loader shouldUseFollowOnLocking
WARN: HHH000444: Encountered request for locking however dialect reports that database prefers locking be done in a separate select (follow-on locking); results will be locked after initial query executes
Hibernate: select field0_.ID as ID1_9_, field0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION2_9_, field0_.NAME as NAME3_9_, field0_.TYPE as TYPE4_9_ from FIELD field0_ where field0_.DESCRIPTION=?
Hibernate: select ID from FIELD where ID =? for update
T1 : FIELD UPDATED
Hibernate: update FIELD set DESCRIPTION=?, NAME=?, TYPE=? where ID=?
T2 : FIELD READ This is a field for testing
T1 : COMMITTED
апр 19, 2019 5:28:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop

T2 : FIELD UPDATED
Hibernate: update FIELD set DESCRIPTION=?, NAME=?, TYPE=? where ID=?
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle]
T2 : COMMITTED

Process finished with exit code 0
```

After the execution the column `description` contains `T2`. It looks like `pessimistic_write` mode works. The transaction who wrote first - won. And this was `T2`. But what happened with T1? `T1 : COMMITTED` is also seen in the output. As long as `T1` doesn't change anything it's acceptable for me, but I need an indicator that `T1` failed, so that I can retry the read/select.

I was wrong. I ran the code multiple times and with different results. Sometimes the column description contains T1, sometimes T2.

Comment: Well the typical approach in Hibernate to this problem is to use *optimistic locking*, let all concurrent session to read the entity and only the first to *commit* the changes, all others get exception due to `version` mismatch and must retry. If this is a user application, implement some *pending* status, that would restrict the selection by other users.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber 'let all concurrent session to read the entity and only the first to commit the changes'. It seems that PESSIMISTIC_WRITE mode does it. The only problem is to get an indicator that the others failed. I've got no exception that T1 failed. Please, look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to make sure that other transactions will NOT READ the queries entities.

For that, you need `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`. This does not allow both READs and UPDATEs. `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ` does not allow only UPDATEs.

> A lock with LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE can be obtained on an
>   entity instance to force serialization among transactions attempting
>   to update the entity data.
>
> A lock with LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE can be used when querying
>   data and there is a high likelihood of deadlock or update failure
>   among concurrent updating transactions.

Comment: It looks like READs are allowed. Please, look at the code I added to my question.